# NextJS index and endpoint share the same page

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have few pages in my Next.js application, and i would like that going into http://localhost:3000/someEndpoint would be exactly the same component loaded as http://localhost:3000/

I already have created index.js file, but i dont know how can make some virtual URL?

Redirections are not the options, cause i would like to remain "/" endpoint also possible.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use nextjs [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites), which works as a URL masking for any URL.

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/someEndpoint',
        destination: '/',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

So now every request on http://localhost:3000/someEndpoint will lands the user to http://localhost:3000/ without redirection. It will work as a proxy url

Comment: do not forget to restart ```yarn dev``` after such change :-)